# В чем ошибка? Не могу понять

Tags: python, python-3.x

Выводит не то, что я хотел бы:

```py
import random
import math
import sys #sys.exit()
input("Нажмите \"Enter\", чтобы продолжить: ")
name = input("Как Вас зовут?: ")
def opportunities(): #cписок опций
    print ("\nПривет " + name  + "!\n"
    "Что будем делать.?"
    "\n1.Учиться."
    "\n2.Решать."
    "\n3.Калькулятор."
    "\n4.Кость."
    "\n5.Крестики нолики (Beta)."
    "\n6.Перевод систем единиц/счислений."
    "\n7.Угадайка."
    "\n8.FAQ.\n"
    "\nВЫХОД - exit")
opportunities()

def Mode(list): #выбор опций
    print("Что выбрали,",name + "?")
    if list == "exit":
        sys.exit()
Mode(list)

if Mode(list) == "1" or Mode(list) == "Учиться" or Mode(list) == "учиться":
        print("чему хотите обучится?"
        "\n1.Матиматике."
        "\n2.Русскому языку."
        "\n3.Физике."
        "\n4.Программированию"
        "\nНАЗАД - back")
        study = str(input(": "))
else:
    print("\nПростите, но я Вас не понял D;" 
    "\n Выберите снова\n")
    Mode(list)
```

[Так выглядет вывод](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rypW3.png).

Comment: Добро пожаловать на stackoverflow. Выкладывайте, пожалуйста, в виде кода, а не картинки. Это в разы упрощает возможность Вам помочь.

Comment: Ваша функция Mode() не поддерживает передачу значений. В самом конце Вы передаёте в него параметр Mode(list)

Comment: не совсем понял. Простите

Comment: У Вас ошибка была в функии, 10 минут назад Вы заменили картинку в вопросе. Что осталось не понятным в переписанном варианте?

Comment: выводит не то,что я хотел бы

Comment: если хотите, чтобы Вам помогли, ещё раз убедительно прошу выложить код. Переписывать это никто не будет. И откорректируйте свой вопрос таким образом, чтобы было понятно, чего Вы хотите добиться.

Comment: Вот понятное и подробное описание функции https://w3schoolsrus.github.io/python/python_functions.html

Comment: Спасибо большое)!

Comment: Поправте заголовок и опишите в вопросе, или ошибку, или неожидаемое поведение вашего кода.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам необходимо возвращать значение в самой функции через return, а так же присвоить переменной результат выполнения функции. В данном случае `hey`

```
import math
import sys #sys.exit()
input("Нажмите \"Enter\", чтобы продолжить: ")
name = input("Как Вас зовут?: ")
def opportunities(): #cписок опций
    print ("\nПривет " + name + "!\n"
    "Что будем делать.?"
    "\n1.Учиться."
    "\n2.Решать."
    "\n3.Калькулятор."
    "\n4.Кость."
    "\n5.Крестики нолики (Beta)."
    "\n6.Перевод систем единиц/счислений."
    "\n7.Угадайка."
    "\n8.FAQ.\n"
    "\nВЫХОД - exit")
opportunities()

def Mode(list): #выбор опций
    print("Что выбрали,",name + "?")
    list = input()
    if list == "exit":
        sys.exit()
    return list
hey = Mode(list)

if hey == "1" or hey == "Учиться" or hey == "учиться":
        print("чему хотите обучится?"
        "\n1.Матиматике."
        "\n2.Русскому языку."
        "\n3.Физике."
        "\n4.Программированию"
        "\nНАЗАД - back")
        study = str(input(": "))
else:
    print("\nПростите, но я Вас не понял D;" 
    "\n Выберите снова\n")
    Mode(list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
#import math
import sys   #sys.exit()

list_to_do = [
    "Учиться",
    "Решать",
    "Калькулятор",
    "Кость",
    "Крестики нолики (Beta)",
    "Перевод систем единиц/счислений",
    "Угадайка",
    "FAQ",
    "exit",
]
list_lesson = [
    "Матиматика",
    "Русский язык",
    "Физика",
    "Программирование",
    "back",
]

input("Нажмите 'Enter', чтобы продолжить: ")
name = input("Как Вас зовут?: ")

def opportunities(list_to_do):                         #cписок опций
    print (f"\nПривет {name} !\n"
           f"Сделайту свой выбор.\n")
    print(*list_to_do, sep='\n')
    while True:
        delo = input("\nЧто будем делать?: ")
        if delo in list_to_do:
            return delo
        else:
            print(f"\nТакого нет в списке дел, повторите свой выбор !\n")


def lessons(delo, list_lesson):
    study = ''
    if delo.lower() == "учиться":
        print("Учиться можно многому:\n")
        print(*list_lesson, sep='\n')
        while True:
            study = input("\nчему хотите научиться?: ")
            if study in list_lesson:
                return study
            else:
                print(f"\nТакого предмета нет в списке, повторите свой выбор !\n")    
    else:
        print(f"{delo} тaк {delo}, это ваш выбор.")
    return study

delo = opportunities(list_to_do)

if delo == "exit":
    print(f"\nВы ничего не собираетесь делать, это печально.")
    sys.exit()
else:
    study = lessons(delo, list_lesson)
    if  study:
        print(f"\nУчить {study}, это правильный выбор.")
```